# Keyframes do not interpolate

Tags: video-sequence-editor, keyframes, interpolation

For some reason, the keyframes I think don't interpolate. It is impossible for me to create two keyframes with different opacity in the same clip but, the strangest thing is that, when trying, the values are reflected in the curve editor, with the line smoothed between the two values, but not in the timesheet, just as it is not reflected in the viewer. I can't even make a simple opacity fade...

[image]

Look at the capture as, the same keyframe has value 1.0 in the curves editor but 0.5 in the timesheet and the video editor. Does anyone know where the rays I have to look to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Very strange. However, the values in the "Editar Clip" Panel don't update while scrubbing/playback (unintuitive, almost buglike). Have you viewed this animated opacity fade in the video editor preview?

Comment: I don't work with the clip editor and no, the video doesn't reflect the opacity animation. Today I will continue to do more tests but there are fewer and fewer things to try.

Comment: Does [this file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6257/) work as expected? Can you compare it to your file?

Comment: The file is working properly. In fact, keyframes work correctly in one scene of the file in question, but not in another scene. For this reason I deduce that there is something in that scene, activated or deactivated, that inhibits the proper functioning. Thanks

Comment: I've compared all the options and configurations I've seen between the two sequences and I don't see any difference. I don't understand how it can happen that the same keyframe has a value in the curves window (that doesn't work) and another different value in the rest of the windows (timesheet and sequence editor). It's incomprehensible.

Comment: You can copy paste sequencer strips from one scene to another in the same file. Try copying all your strips into a new scene, does the problem persist?

Comment: I finally found the problem thanks to your file, looking at the listing window. Deleting the copied ANL tracks from the original scene was solved. Thank you very much! I should learn to use the program beyond the video editor to understand its operating base... but the editor is so good (surpassing Premiere in many respects) that I started directly on the video editor. Thank you very much again. Greetings.

Comment: Oh, so you had some additional NLA tracks floating around? Glad you solved your problem. The NLA editor is quite confusing if you haven't used it before. I would urge you to post this step as an answer below. That way others can be helped by the same solution. It would be nice if you included a description how to find the nla editor.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved,

Copying the scene also copied the ANL tracks from the original scene. By deleting them from the List window, the keyframes can now be worked on properly. I still need to understand some basic Blender functions which, when I start directly with the video editor, I still don't control.

Thanks leander and Greetings